# How to combine data from both a .json and .list file in an alternating fashion using python to dump into new JSON file?

Tags: python, json, list, file

Essentially, my task is to extract information first from a JSON file and then from a .list file. This information is then in an alternating sequence to be dumped into a new JSON file called `summary.json`.

My approach so far is to extract all the json data to one list and then the list data to another list. From there, I add that information all 1 index at a time to a new combined list which is to be dumped.

```
# append json_data to list1
json_data = []
for i in json_files:
    with open(i) as f:
        json_data.append(json.load(f))

# append table_data to list2
table_data = []
for i in table_files:
    with open(i) as f:
        for line in f:
            table_data.append(line)

#format data to remove \n characters
table_data = [sub.replace('\n', '') for sub in table_data]

#combine list info
combined = []
while True:
    try:
        combined.append(json_data.pop(0))
        combined.append(table_data.pop(0))
    except IndexError:
        break

# dump list info to new json file
with open('summary.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(combined, f, indent=2)
```

Here is the output with my current code:

```
[
  {
    "json_object1_item1": "value1",
    "json_object1_item2": "value2",
    "json_object1_item3": "value3"
  },
  tablelist1_item1,
  {
    "json_object2_item1": "value1",
    "json_object2_item2": "value2",
    "json_object2_item3": "value3"
  }
 tablelist1_item2
]
```

The desired output is something like:

```
[
  {
    "json_object1_item1": "value1",
    "json_object1_item2": "value2",
    "json_object1_item3": "value3"
  },
  tablelist1_item1,
  tablelist1_item2,
  tablelist1_item3,
  {
    "json_object2_item1": "value1",
    "json_object2_item2": "value2",
    "json_object2_item3": "value3"
  }
 tablelist2_item1,
 tablelist2_item2,
 tablelist2_item3
]
```

How can I fix my code to get what I need? Is there a better approach to achieving my output? Thanks

Comment: Do you always want 3 items from the `table_data` for each one from `json_data`?

Comment: No that's just for example. There's always going to be a varying number of items from ```table_data``` but I essentially want 1 ```table_data``` file for each ```json_data``` file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are only getting one value from the `table_data` is because you have flattened it, e.g. `[1,2,3,4,5,6]` instead of `[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]`, e.g.:

```
table_data = []
for i in table_files:
    with open(i) as f:
        table_data.append([line.rstrip('\n') for line in f])
```

And then you need to flatten it in your combine. The use of `extend` flattens the `table_data`. `zip()` is an easier way of combining two lists and will stop when one or other list is exhausted:

```
combined = []
for j, t in zip(json_data, table_data):
    combined.append(j)
    combined.extend(t)
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you. Also would it be possible to group each ```json_file``` and ```table_data``` pair together based on the first value of each json object?

Comment: eg.
``` "value1": {
          "json_object1_item1": "value1",
          "json_object1_item2": "value2", }
           tablelist1_item1 } ```

Comment: It is unclear how you are doing this grouping. It might be worth asking another question providing more details.